# NASM, MASM, Intel, AT&T' syntax?

Tags: assembly, nasm, intel

I see  word NASM, MASM, Intel, AT&T. I am confused between them. Is it different types of assembly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing several things.

`nasm`, `masm` and `gas` (GNU Assembler) are tools that compile an x86 assembly text file into an executable. Each of them do have a specific syntax to specify  your program. But, they share a lot on assembly instructions.

Then, Intel and AT&T are specific syntax to write x86 assembly programs. In fact, `nasm` and `masm` use the Intel syntax, where `gas` is using the AT&T syntax.

Comment: gas has support for both, Intel syntax requires that you use the .intel_syntax directive. However, you'd  be better off using a different assembler if you want to use Intel syntax.